# Clearing (and restoring) default value from text input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text box which have initial value written in, i wanna that box to be clear when it is clicked(active).

Ex:
  //wanna it to be clear when clicked to enter a value from user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with javascript look at the onclick event. Here a small example:

```
<input type="text" onclick="this.value='';" />
```

Comment: what if i want the text appear back,when the user didn't enter text,and clicked out of the box??

Comment: something like this should work: onblur="this.value = (this.value == '') ? 'myText' : this.value" onfocus="this.value = ''" value="myText" i also think instead of onclick you should use onfocus and onblur which was suggest by the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of the above solutions are very good - inline events is **not** a good solution in this case. What you'll want is to use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute, and with a bit of Javascript, add support for it for browsers that do not support it. Your HTML will look something like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="search" />
```

This will work with the current versions of Safari and Chrome. For the other browsers, you can use this Javascript:

```
// Creates a new element and check if it has the 'placeholder' property
// If it does not, then we know that the browser does not support HTML5 placeholder
if(typeof document.createElement('input').placeholder === 'undefined'){
    // Find the input element with the id "search" and get the 'placeholder' attribute
    var input = document.getElementById('search'), 
        p = input.getAttribute('placeholder');

    // Give it the placeholder value
    input.value = p;

    // Clear input on focus, then add the placeholder text 
    // back in if there's nothing there after the user changes edits the box
    input.onfocus = function(){
        if(this.value === p) this.value = '';
    }
    input.onblur = function(){
        if(!this.value) this.value = p;
    }
}
```

You can see a simple demo of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/RT8Bf/

Comment: the online example works,but doesn't work in my browser, even in the online example there are no initial value however it appears as 'search',,and copied and pasted it and didn't work or even the word 'search' appeared.
what to do??

Comment: @OdO What do you mean? You first say it works, then it doesn't. What browser are  you using? What do mean when you say "there are no initial value however it appears as 'search'"? Isn't that the point of the placeholder text, to appear when there isn't something in the input element? And stop copying and pasting code around - learn how the code works, then use it yourself.

Comment: i mean that when i try it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/RT8Bf/
it works.
But when i write the code in HTML file and try to run it on my pc it doesn't work,even the word 'search' doesn't appear in the box.
my browser is firefox latest version.

Answer (score 3):

just write

```
 <input type='text' name='myText' onFocus='this.value="";'/>
```

**UPDATED:**
if you want value back if nothing is entered

```
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value=='Search') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Search';" value="Search" />
```

Comment: You can also use `this.defaultValue` instead of a literal.

Comment: @nikc Thanx for suggesting better way